# Python Library to Connect to Solace Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, solace-mq

I want to send json objects to Solace queue using python.
Is there any library in Python to work with Solace queue.
If yes, Please let me know the library and how to work with it.
Thank you.
-Praveen

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try searching first before asking a question. https://solace.com/samples/solace-samples-semp/messagevpn-with-queue-python/

Comment: This only helps to create solace queue. Not to fetch json object and send to queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON` library from Python, [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).
Assuming you already have the sender and receiver like this [example](https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-amqp-qpid-proton-python/blob/master/src/simple_send.py#L96). A simple code is given below:

```py
import json

# Create a json object
sample_data = {'name':'Praveen'}
json_data = json.dumps(sample_data)
# Use sender
event.sender.send(json_data)
```

You can also look at another [example](https://solace.com/samples/solace-samples-semp/messagevpn-with-queue-python/) and link to code on [Github](https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-semp/blob/master/python/samples/manage_vpn.py#L99).

Comment: Thank you so much Mrinal. It helps.